# How do I connect Scarlett Solo Audio Interface to Ubuntu for best results?

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I use Ubuntu 16.04. As a long-time Ubuntu user, I would not like to switch to Windows for Audio Recording. Can you assist me? I am not getting optimal sound from my mic.

Scarlett Solo is an Audio Interface that does not provide drivers for Ubuntu. I have the Gen 3 Scarlett. I will now list how I have gone about connecting the Scarlett to Ubuntu. I am using the Reaper software. I hope this process will help other users like me. I was not able to find a one-stop source on the internet.

1. I connected the Scarlett and found that PulseAudio reads it. However, I learned from [here](https://dragly.org/2014/01/12/focusrite-scarlett-2i2-flawlessly-working-on-ubuntu-with-jack/) to use JACK instead.

   [image: JACK default]
2. I made no changes in JACK settings.
3. In Sound options → *Input*, I chose *Digital Input*.

   [image: Digital Input in place of Analog]
4. In Sound options → *Output*, I chose *Headphones*.

   [image: Headphones to listen to the sound]
5. Now, I went to the popular and useful channel of [Reaper Mania on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dD_xXJC4sJY&ab_channel=REAPERMania) and learned that I must set the *Device* in Reaper to - *Scarlett Solo*.
6. However, Reaper does not read this device. So I chose *JACK* as *Device*.

   [image: JACK as Device]
7. But I got this error instead:

   [image: Error]
8. I am able to record sound, though it does not sound to be of optimum quality. This issue mentioned [here](https://thanede.wordpress.com/2017/07/03/getting-a-focusrite-scarlett-solo-to-work-under-linux-common-issues/).

   > Issue: Microphone recordings are distorted/contain static/are
   > unbalanced (left channel).
9. Where do I go from here? What's the best way to get the best sound on Ubuntu? Is there a way to get the best sound without the drivers? Or do I have to go to Windows as [this link implies](https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/forum/redirect/post?p=33865200)?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you succed ? i have the same problem

Comment: Sebastien, did you manage a solution? I believe I checked the volume settings and skipped JACK eventually. Let me know.